# Excel/VBA - Set Focus and Scroll to Control

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looping through the ActiveX controls on my spreadsheet to implement tab control. I have around 100 controls in my spreadsheet, so not everything fits on a single "page" (it's all in the same tab, you just have to scroll down.)

I can use Activate to set the focus to the next control. However, when I tab through the controls and pass the bottom of the viewable window, the window doesn't automatically scroll to show the control with focus.

Is there a way to get the spreadsheet to scroll so that the control that has focus is actually on the screen?

Comment: Look at Application.Windows(indexOfWindow).ScrollRow or ScrollColumn or ScrollIntoView

Answer (score 0):

Sorceri nailed it right on the head. I used [Window.ScrollRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821595.aspx) to scroll down the page after I set the focus. The only issue is that this sets the bottom of the row to the top of the window, so it's just off screen. I was able to resolve this by specifying:

```
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = row-3
```

Thanks!